# ESLINT new-cap error

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, eslint

I'm using ESLINT to analyze my code. The code runs fine. It's highlighting "Datastore". This is sample code from Google Cloud Platform Datastore examples.

[eslint] A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor. (new-cap)

```
// Instantiates a client
const datastore = Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
});
```

Here's `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {   extends: 'google',   parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,   }, };
```

Answer (score 8):

You can configuration the `rules` in your `.eslintrc`, It looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    // "extends": "airbnb"
    "extends": "google",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 8,
    },
    "rules": {
      "new-cap": 0,
    }
};
```

- level 0 — disables the rule
- level 1 — makes it a warning
- level 2 — makes it an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to Google Cloud. It's related to your eslint configs. To remove this you can do either of the following:

- while importing datastore use this method:

  `var gcloud = require('google-cloud');
  var datastore = gcloud.datastore({
  projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
  });`
- or update your options for eslint. You can do this by adding it on top of the file

  `/*eslint new-cap: ["error", { "newIsCap": false }]*/`